# Clarifai This API call was not sucessful

Tags: java, image, clarifai

I was trying some concepts with Clarifai locally using java, from some images I have on my computer. The idea was to get 30 concepts for each of the images which would then be saved as tags in the application I am developing. Initially the code was working and I printed the result for each one of the images in the folder I'm reading from, but a little more than an hour ago I left the following error:
[image]

Below I leave the java code I was using to get the concepts of my images:

```
protected static String getConcepts(String path, String API_KEY) {

    /*Vou obter 30 conceitos para uma determinada imagem*/
    
    String result = "";
    ClarifaiClient client = new ClarifaiBuilder(API_KEY).client(new OkHttpClient()).buildSync();

    final List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> predictionResults = client.getDefaultModels().generalModel().predict().
    withInputs(ClarifaiInput.forImage(new File(path))).withMaxConcepts(5).executeSync().get();

    Iterator<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> resultTags = predictionResults.iterator();
    TreeMap<String, Float> tags = new TreeMap<>();
    int numberOfTags;

    if (resultTags.hasNext()) {
        ClarifaiOutput<Concept> next = resultTags.next();
        numberOfTags = next.data().size();

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfTags; j++) {
            Concept concept = next.data().get(j);
            String name = concept.name();
            tags.put(concept.name(), concept.value());
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Float> entry : tags.entrySet()) {
        result += entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue() + ",";
    }

    System.out.println( result);
    return result;
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     /*ClarifaiClient client = new ClarifaiBuilder("b5bc3cb6b7ba4a8cbd6d950c811c18b3").buildSync();

     final List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> response =
         // You can also do client.getModelByID("id") to get your custom model
         client.getDefaultModels().generalModel()
                 .predict()
                 .withInputs(ClarifaiInput.forImage("https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg"))
                 .executeSync()
                 .get();
     
     System.out.println(response);*/
    //String src = "/home/claudia/Desktop/EmotionROI/images/anger/selected_images/";
    //String img = "12.jpg";
    //String dest = src+"teste"+img;
    
    //Lista de ficheiros do diretório - obtenção dos ficheiros
    String pathDir = "/home/claudia/Desktop/EmotionROI/images/anger/selected_images/";
    File imageFile = new File(pathDir);
    File[] listFiles = imageFile.listFiles();
    //System.out.println("Os meus ficheiros são: ");
    
    String resultF = "";
    List<String> listTagImg = new ArrayList<>();
    //ciclo que vai permitir aceder ao nome dos ficheiros
    for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {
        String nameFiles = listFiles[i].getName();
        //System.out.println(nameFiles);
        
        //criação de um pah novo com o nome de cada um dos ficheiros
        String pahtFiles = pathDir+nameFiles;
        listTagImg.add(pahtFiles);
    }
    List<String> listTags = new ArrayList<>();
    String line="";
    for (int j = 0; j < listFiles.length; j++) {
        //System.out.println("lista"+listTagImg.get(j));
        line += getConcepts(listTagImg.get(j), "b5bc3cb6b7ba4a8cbd6d950c811c18b3");
        
    }
    //getConcepts(listTagImg.get(), "241b3315671f4baeaec399186c435022");
    
    System.out.println(line);
```

What am I doing roung?

Comment: I'd look at the "Details about the error" part of the partially cut-off picture of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This (the illegal reflective access Warning) can happen in older versions of protobuf.  What version are you using?  Are you able to update?

The API should be using 3.12.0, but I've seen instances where an older installed version was used unexpectedly.

Just saw that the error message you're getting is actually NoSuchElementException so the Clarifai network error is probably not related to an outage or network issues like I originally suspected.

Would be helpful to know what line 134 is in your `getConcepts` function to see if it is passing something odd to the Clarifai API which might be choking on it.